# Create an author archive page with views

Tags: views, nodes

I have two content types: article and author. The author content type has a bio, links to facebook and twitter etc. This author content type is connected to the article content type with an entity reference. I want to create a page that displays the author content at the top and then below that, a list of all the authors most recent articles.

I am trying to make a view block with a contextual filter to drop into the author page, but I cannot get it to work. I dont really understand views that well. Can anyone give me some pointers on what I need to do to set this up?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to create a view of articles and add a contextual filter for the node reference field.

How are you attaching the view to a node? Is it a views attachment? Is it a panel pane á la Page Manager? That will determine the specifics of how your view parses the argument out of the URL.

Comment: What is the node reference field? Is that the author field that I have attached to my article content type?

I am attaching the views block to the author page via the context module.

Comment: Yes, it's the author field.